# Time Complexity of a Bounded Knapsack problem

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

For the bounded knapsack with repetition problem, I am given a knapsack with capacity, W. I must fill the knapsack such that I maximize the total value of items inside the knapsack, where each item has an associated weight and value, w and v. However, I can only have a maximum of K of each items. I found an algorithm that does this and I believe it runs with a time complexity of O(Wn). But, I've found a lot of sources that says it could be O(WKn). Why would it be O(WKn) if that is the correct time complexity?

For transparency, this is indeed a homework problem. I just need assistance on why the time complexity is O(WKn), unless the sources I read were completely wrong.

Comment: Think of it as a dynamic programming problem where you need to test n items combined K to K with capacity W.

You would have a minimum of three for loops, one for the n items, one for K and one for until you reach w capacity.  The `K` in the complexity stems then from the fact that different combinations of K items are possible inside n since obviously for it to make any sense `k<n`

Comment: Got it. Thank you! Is there a way to optimize the runtime to make it faster than O(WKn)?

Comment: please refer to this link for a general explanation of an optimization : https://algomath.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/limited-number-items-knapsack/

its a different version but it might apply to what you can do with your items